# SQLBase Error: 00905 PRS MRP Missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, sqlbase

I'm trying to select the most recent inspection record for each unit in our DB, which is running on SQLBase 11.7. I thought maybe I could do something like

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 
FROM Insp_Header 
WHERE (unit_id, insp_dt) IN (SELECT unit_id, MAX(insp_dt) 
                             FROM Insp_Header 
                             GROUP BY unit_id);
```

but I get the error in the title when I try this. I also tried to get around this by using an explicit join,

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM Insp_header 
INNER JOIN (
     SELECT unit_id, MAX(insp_dt) 
     FROM Insp_Header GROUP BY unit_id) meh 
        ON Insp_Header.unit_id=meh.unit_id 
        AND Insp_Header.insp_dt=meh.insp_dt;
```

and when that didn't work, an implicit one.

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 
FROM Insp_Header
, (  SELECT unit_id, MAX(insp_dt) 
     FROM Insp_Header GROUP BY unit_id) meh 
     WHERE Insp_Header.unit_id=meh.unit_id 
     AND Insp_Header.insp_dt=meh.insp_dt;
```

Both resulted in the same error mentioned in the title. The only difference is that the arrow indicating where the error occurred pointed to the comma in the expression between the WHERE and IN keywords in my original attempt and now the arrow is pointing to the comma after the first column in the SELECT clause of the subquery. I'm struggling to think of a way to make this work or an alternate way to accomplish the same goal. Any suggestions would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: None of the above queries have a missing right parenthesis. Something else must cause the error.

Comment: @jarlh I agree, and I've been wracking my brain trying to figure out what that might be, or at least come up with an alternative query that accomplishes the same goal, but I'm struggling to come up with anything workable.

Comment: Is Insp_Header perhaps a view?

Comment: @jarlh I don't believe so. I just checked the system catalog tables and was able to find INSP_HEADER listed in systables but not in sysviews. So, it looks to me to be a regular table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the examples given so far are no way SQLBase syntax.
You're obviously thinking of SQLServer .
The following is quick and easy ( and SQLBase syntax ), and using Travis Shands very first example - simply replace the ',' in the Where clause with '||'

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 
FROM Insp_Header 
WHERE (unit_id || insp_dt) IN (SELECT unit_id || MAX(insp_dt) 
                               FROM Insp_Header 
                               GROUP BY unit_id);
```

p.s. For your future reference, using words like

> 'unfortunately is SQLBase 11.7'

does little to encourage SQLBase fans to help you .

Comment: You are right on both accounts good sir. I was feeling really frustrated after spending several hours searching online and digging through documentation but struggling to find any indication that what I was trying to do was even possible in SQLBase. I wouldn't suggest that this justifies such petty behavior however, so I've removed the disparaging remark from my original question and I do apologize. I would also like to thank you for being gracious enough to answer despite my admittedly hostile tone. This appears to be exactly what I needed, thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the admission. And the useful vote ? :)   I understand you may not be a fan, and at the risk of sounding fanatic ( I am in no way affiliated ) , please consider if you get the opportunity, to move your database to the next generation of SQLBase.... v12.nn .  Currently v12.3 .    The difference from an ancient v11 is like night and day,   and the performance increase ( when properly configured and tuned ) will blow you away. And in case you don't have it, here is a link to all the current SQLBase manuals:  https://samples.tdcommunity.net/index.php?dir=SqlBase/SqlBase_Books/